# Debounce Vuex Action Call to Database Not Working

Tags: vue.js, vuex, debouncing

I have a few components that can be separate or on the same page.  Each of these components uses the same **Vuex** state.  Since they can each be used on other pages and still work, each of them dispatches a call to the same **Vuex** *action* which in turns calls a service that uses **axios** to get the JSON data.

All of this works great!

However, when I do have 2 (or more) of these components on a single page, that *axios* call gets called 1 time for each of the components.  Initially, I went down the path of trying to see if data existed and get created a "last got data at" timestamp so I could just bypass the 2nd call.  However, these are happening both on the components `created` event and are being essentially called at the same time.

So, enter `debounce`.  Seems like the exact reason for this.  However, when I implement it, it fails and is passing on to the next line of code and not `awaiting`.  What am I doing wrong?

### Agenda Component (one that uses the same state)

```
async created() {
  await this.gatherCalendarData();
},
methods: {
  async gatherCalendarData() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('time/dateSelected', this.$store.state.time.selectedDate);
  },
},
```

### Month Component (another, notice they are the same)

```
async created() {
  await this.gatherCalendarData();
},
methods: {
  async gatherCalendarData() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('time/dateSelected', this.$store.state.time.selectedDate);
  },
},
```

### The Action getting called

```
async dateSelected(context, data) {
  let result = await getCalendarData(isBetween.date, context.rootState.userId);
  await context.commit('SET_MONTHLY_DATA', { result: result.Result, basedOn: isBetween.date });
},
```

This `getCalendarData` method is in a service file I created to make api calls (below.)

This is the error that I receive (once for each component) that calls this action.

`[Vue warn]: Error in created hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Result' of undefined"`

Which is referring to the 3rd line above: `result: result.Result`

### API Service

```
const getCalendarData = debounce(async (givenDate, userId) => {
  let response = await getCalendarDataDebounced(givenDate, userId);
  return response;
}, 100);

const getCalendarDataDebounced = async (givenDate, userId) => {
  let result = await axiosGet('/api/v2/ProjectTime/BuildAndFillCalendarSQL', {
    givenDate: givenDate,
    userID: userId,
  });

  return result;
};
```

### Axios Wrapper

```
const axiosGet = async (fullUrl, params) => {
  let result = null;

  try {
    let response = await axios.get(fullUrl, params ? { params: params } : null);
    result = await response.data;
  } catch(error) {
    console.error('error:', error);
  }

  return result;
};
```

If I put `console.log` messages before, after and inside the `getCalendarData` call as well as in the `getCaledarDataDebounced` methods: (assuming just 2 components on the page) the 2 before logs show up and then the 2 after logs appear.  Next the error mentioned above for each of the 2 components, then a single 'inside the `getCalendarData`' is logged and finally the log from within the debounced version where it actually gets the data.

So it seems like the debouncing is working in that it is only run a single time.  But it appears that `await` call `let result = await getCalendarData(isBetween.date, context.rootState.userId);` is not truly Waiting.

Am I missing something here?

### EDITS after Answer

Based on @JakeHamTexas' answer, my `action` of `dateSelected` is now (actual full code, nothing removed like above as to not confuse anything):

```
async dateSelected(context, data) {
  console.log('dateSelected action');
  let isBetween = isDateWithinCurrentMonth(data, context.state);

  if (!isBetween.result) {
    // The date selected is in a different month, so grab that months data
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      getCalendarData(isBetween.date, context.rootState.userId)
        .then(result => {
          console.log('inside promise');
          context.commit('SET_MONTHLY_DATA', { result: result.Result, basedOn: isBetween.date });
          context.commit('SET_SELECTED_DATE', isBetween.date);
          context.commit('statistics/TIME_ENTRIES_ALTERED', true, { root: true });
          resolve();
        });
    });
  } else {
    // The date selected is within the given month, so simply select it
    context.commit('SET_SELECTED_DATE', data);
  }

  context.commit('CLEAR_SELECTED_TIME_ENTRY_ID');
},
```

And my API call of `getCalendarData` is now:

```
const getCalendarData = async (givenDate, userId) => {
  console.log('getting calendar data');
  let result = await axiosGet('/api/v2/ProjectTime/BuildAndFillCalendarSQL', {
    givenDate: givenDate,
    userID: userId,
  });

  return result;
};
```

The error is gone!  However, it does not seem to be `debouncing` - meaning everything gets called 3 times.  I would expect the `dateSelected action` to be called 3 times.  But I would like to avoid the `getting calendar data` being called 3 times.  If it helps, this is what the console looks like:

```
dateSelected action
getting calendar data
dateSelected action
getting calendar data
dateSelected action
getting calendar data
inside promise
inside promise
inside promise
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise from your action. Returning a promise of undefined (which is what is currently happening) resolves immediately.

```js
dateSelected(context, data) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    getCalendarData(isBetween.date, context.rootState.userId)
    .then(result => {
      context.commit('SET_MONTHLY_DATA', { result: result.Result, basedOn: isBetween.date });
      resolve();
    }
  }
},
```

Additionally, a vuex `commit` does not return a promise, so it doesn't make sense to await it.

Comment: I have finally had the time to come back to this, thank you for your answer, I have edited my code and question above.  Still calling API 3 times.

Comment: Can you @JakeHamTexas give any suggestions based on my edits?